# HttpURLConnection GET request not returning anything

Tags: android, get, httpurlconnection

I am trying to execute a GET request, however even though there is no error in the log, the request returns nothing.

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Log.v("info", "get request starting"); //This message is showing in the console
                URL url = new URL("http://192.168.0.16:8888/piapi/index.php/piapi/getinfo");
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
                InputStream stream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
                String line;
                Log.v("info", "Request executed"); //This is not showing
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line); // Doesn't show anything
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  
            } catch (IOException e) {    //No error in the log file
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

I have also tried to put it in a Asynctask class, and with several URLs but none of these options worked. Any suggestion ? Thanks.

Comment: Put membrane SOA proxy in between

Comment: What happens when you go to here in the internet browser? It looks strange to have a path after the file. http://192.168.0.16:8888/piapi/index.php/piapi/getinfo

Comment: As above, the url doesn't seem valid? You'd usually have a '?' after .php and some sort of valid request i.e. index.php?action=some_data_want_to_get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: it turns out the code is working just fine, however Android Wear  (I did not specified it as I didn't think it had any kind of influence) doesn't allow direct access to the Internet via the watch, that's why it wasn't working. Thanks anyway.